# Ninject contstructor multiple interface parameter

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ninject

How do you inject mutiple param using ninject?
example:

```
IWeapon weap;
ISheild sheld;
ISoap isoap;
public myclass(IWeapon weapon, IShield shield, ISoap soap)
{
    weap = weapon;
    sheld = shield;
    isoap = soap;
}
```

already tried this it gave me a ninject activation exception all I did to bind them was to use

```
kernel.Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>();
kernel.Bind<IShield>().To<DragonSheild>();
kernel.Bind<ISoap>().To<Safeguard>();
```

I cannot run my project it keeps giving me a ninject exception.

Comment: Please, add exception details to your question. Also show code which throws that exception

Comment: Can you share the exception details with us?

Comment: An exception of type 'Ninject.ActivationException' occurred in Ninject.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Error activating IPOSJobService using binding from IPOSJobService to POSJobService
A cyclical dependency was detected between the constructors of two services.

Comment: Activation path:
  5) Injection of dependency IPOSJobService into parameter posJobService of constructor of type TerminalService
  4) Injection of dependency ITerminalService into parameter terminalService of constructor of type POSJobService
  3) Injection of dependency IPOSJobService into parameter posJobService of constructor of type UserService
  2) Injection of dependency IUserService into parameter userService of constructor of type LoginController
  1) Request for LoginController

Comment: Suggestions:
  1) Ensure that you have not declared a dependency for IPOSJobService on any implementations of the service.
  2) Consider combining the services into a single one to remove the cycle.
  3) Use property injection instead of constructor injection, and implement IInitializable
     if you need initialization logic to be run after property values have been injected.

Comment: Thanks @BartvanNierop and Sergey Berezovskiy

Comment: Is there still something you'd like to know? I think the exception describes clearly what the problem is. If not, please update your question with the details you provided in the comments and explain what what the problem is.

Comment: ah ok.. hehe.. didnt read it..

Comment: Thanks guys! by the way you guys know any open source AOP framework that could do logging and security?

Comment: @user2080671 That sounds like a new question to me.

Answer (score 0):

The example you gave is not from your application right?
I think your application looks like this:

```
public class TerminalService : ITerminalService
{
  public TerminalService(IPOSJobService posJobService){}
}

public class POSJobService : IPOSJobService
{
  public class POSJobService(ITerminalService terminalsService){}
}
```

If it's true then the problem is clear. The two class has cross reference each other.
It's some kind a parent-child relation, but the dependency should be one way.